Duo Cam Functionality
I am building a react native app and I need to be able to stream duo cam. I have been able to access duo cam with IOS native, however I cannot access the duo cam functionality of Agora and I cannot find the documentation for assistance.
trying to stream each cam separately but it is a time consuming task and not sure if it will work. Can you provide some documentation for the right path?
